# Simple ways to compare two strings without Strcmp in c

Tags: c, turbo-c

I need to compare the  user enter values in string two string without using Inbuilt functions or(strcmp) in c. i have used first program  by using other languages its not working so i have created the second one as working in c ,is there any better way without  while loop:

This question will help the people who have some basic knowledge in c and good understanding knowledge  like javascript or any other oops language programmers suddenly interest to learn c programming  concepts how c  string manipulation gets different from other languages and want to play with string manipulation without using any built-in function in c.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        char ch[80];
        printf("Enter Your name:" );
        if(scanf("%s",ch) =="hello")
        {
            printf("hello");
        }
        else if(scanf("%s",ch) =="saythanku")
        {
            printf("saythanku");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("none");
        }
    }


Working:


#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{

printf("enter your name");
char ch[80];

scanf("%s",ch);
int a=compare(ch,"hello");

if(a==0)
{
    printf("hello");
}
else
{
    printf("not hello");
}
}
int compare(char a[], char b[])
{
   int c = 0;

   while( a[c] == b[c] )
   {
      if( a[c] == '\0' || b[c] == '\0' )
         break;
       c++;
   }
   if( a[c] == '\0' && b[c] == '\0' )
      return 0;
   else
      return -1;
}
```

simple any otherways to compare

Comment: C is not C++ is not C#

Comment: Surprised that code even compiles. Also, why do you not want to use the function that is **explicitly designed to compare strings in C**?

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison. `' hello'` is a single multi-byte character, not a string.

Comment: Stop writing `C` code using another language as a model.  You don't learn the language that way.

Comment: You need to read more about how to work with character array in C

Comment: Besides errors in your code, without `strcmp` you can alternatively use [`memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp) or use loops comparing character by character.

Comment: oh my god this is such a guesswork and then instead of learning what each individual part does you come here to ask for help. lazy.

Comment: how could this be more wrong?

Comment: i blame people who provide easy answers to get points. i think this should be penalized or we'll keep getting more and more of homework questions.

Comment: Your latest update is still guessing (and you should not be changing the original code anyway).  Where are character strings in `C` surrounded by single quotes?  This goes to my previous comment --- stop using other languages rules when writing `C`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",ch) =='hello'` does not mean what you expect. Read the man page or your beginners textbook what the return value of this function means.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie  thanks for your replies because of much more understanding of languages  how c gets different from other programming models in conventions.

Comment: what is sense of scanf("%s",ch) =='hello'

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by PaulMcKenzie, it seems that you apply concepts of other languages directly to the c programming language, mostly by guessing. If you do not have a book to start with, use at least google to find some tutorials. For example, I entered "c strings introduction" and got - among others - this [link](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-strings), which explains a lot of the issues you are currently having.

The following does not answer your question or even solve your homework, but maybe it gives you enough hints to start.

A "string" in c is an array of characters, terminated by a `0` (often written as `'\0'`.

String literals are enclosed in double quotes, i.e. `"hello"` (not `'hello'`).

Single characters of a string can be accessed by an index, e.g. `char c = ch[0]` of `char c = ch[5]` or `int i=3; char c = ch[i]`.

A loop that iterates through the characters of a string and looks for an `A` could look as follows:

```
int i=0;
int found = 0;
while (!found && i < 80 && ch[i] != '\0') {
   if (ch[i] == 'A')
     found = 1;

   i++;
}
```

This is not meant as an answer; It is just that I am a beginner, too (though in other fields than C); and beginners should help beginners :-)
Have fun learning C, use google and good books, and be aware that it will take some time.

Comment: thanks stephen suddenly i thought to learn c because of performance wise c and c++ occupies in first read by articles therefore apply the other language sand c instructions comparing and learning, while string manipulation somewhat struggling in c, so posted as question to get different thought of a progrmmersi am new to c ,and know string contains group of characters , so the collection will be split out by characters and will check and process it by using itertaions . I will read more articles and learn c string manipulations more to improve logical wise